# Time complexity of LP problems

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

In almost all websites and papers, the complexity of LP problem is given in the number of iterations (such as https://or.stackexchange.com/a/5924). I was wondering if there are any references where worst-case "time"  complexity is discussed. Like, the time to solve LP problem is bounded above by...?